# Re-post ajax reguest if changes done in field

Tags: jquery

I am using ajax to post data. It's working fine.

Here's the processing, I am using this function to check if the email is already added in the database or not. when I type email in the email field and submit the data, it checks in the database and responds accordingly.
If it already added in DB, it shows the message "This email already exists". The problem starts here, If if re-enter email in the email field without reloading the page, then ajax function does not work and it reloads the page.

I want if users make changes in the email without reloading the page, then it should check again, and if the email is already in DB, it should display the message else form should submit.

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $(".signup_btn").click(function(e){
            var email = $("#email").val();
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({ 
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {"email": email },
                  url: "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>check_user.php" ,
                  success: function (response) {
                      //alert(response);
                      if(response == "found") {
                        $(".error-message").html('<p style="color:red">This email already exist</p>');
                      } else {
                        $(".signup_form").submit();
                      }
                  },
                  error: function(){ 
                    alert('Something went wrong');
                  }
          });
       });
    });
```

Please have a look and provide me a working solution.
Thanks

Comment: If at the second time on re-entering the email the page reloads, it's probably hitting the else statement, which submits the form. Can you give the response data from the ajax request?

Comment: Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/t8vqux

I have just returned "found", if record found in database. Please let me know what else you need to check.

I don't think that form is submitting because password field is required and also data is not inserted in database. It just reloads the page.

Comment: Please attach code of your HTML form.

Comment: Thank for your help, it was going in else condition and form was not submitting properly.
I just made change in else condition and now it's working fine.

Here's the code


                       } else {
                        $(".signup_btn").unbind('click').click(); 
                       }
Thanks again